# How to help my Dracaena Dragon trunk

Tags: dracaena

My trunk has grown so high only foliage is at top. 2 yrs old but it touches ceiling. No way I can leave outside during winter.

Can I cut back the trunk without killing it?

[image: Plant with tall, thin trunk and leaves at height.]

Answer (score 3):

You can cut it off. I do it most years, then root top and let bottom grow. They will root in water or soil if kept moist. You can cut several sections from the trunk and root all. I have 3 different dracaenas I treat the same.

Comment: Long ago, the first dracaena  got was a 4in. length of trunk . It has been cut 20 times over the years.